# Trouble making a header file

Tags: c++, header-files

I am trying to make my own header file which will contain a class `Vector`.
To create a header file, as advised by some websites, I have created two different files :-

1) collections.h (contains declarations) 
2) collections.cpp (contains definition)

Another file is main.cpp, which contains the main function, and in which I will be using collections.h

All these files are in the same directory

The trouble I am having is that compiler is showing the error

`Undefined reference to Vector::Vector(int, int)`

and so on for all the functions in my class.

I have made sure that there is a `#include "collections.h"` line in both collections.cpp as well as main.cpp

How can I solve the above problem?

I am using gcc compiler under ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build *both* source files and link them together.

On a Linux command line, you can do it simplest by providing both source files to `gcc`:

```
$ g++ -Wall main.cpp collections.cpp -o my_program
```

**Note:** I added the `-Wall` option to enable more warnings by default. It's always a very good habit to enable more warnings, as they can often point out logical errors or possible places where you have undefined behavior.

Comment: It is still showing errors like `undefined reference to std::cout` even though I have used `using namespace std ;` in my main.cpp

Comment: use g++ then instead of gcc

Comment: @ps06756 Oops, used wrong compiler. For C++ code use `g++` (updated my answer).

Answer (score 2):

First build the object files:

```
gcc -c main.cpp -o main.o
gcc -c collections.cpp -o collections.o
```

then link them together:

```
gcc collections.o main.o -o main
```